# Ruby: how to show hash keys and values as an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I want to display my answer hash keys and values as an array (in normal English, we call it a 'set of answers'; not to be confused with programming term 'set' which is different). So, instead of `{a => 12} {b => 10}`, I can show `[a, 12] [b, 10]`.

I know how to print/return the values, but I want to show the keys for the corresponding values as well.

I am checking a bunch of numbers in an array to see which of them add up to a number I am looking for. For example: ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6). I can get the function to do all the operations and give me the result. But I want the result to be displayed as an array of answers (or in English, 'a set of answers'), not just as hash. So, for the above example, the answer would look like: `[1, 5] [2,4]`.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = 5

def two_sum(array, x)
  set_nums = {}
  array.each do |y|
    difference = x - y
    if set_nums[difference]
      return set_nums
    end
    set_nums[y] = difference
  end
  return 'unable to find pairs'
end
puts two_sum(array, x)
```

I want to get `[1, 4], [2, 3]`

Actual now: `{1=>4, 2=>3}`

Comment: `p two_sum(array, x).to_a`

Comment: I think you mean "array", not "set". See [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). Also, to check whether a hash `h` has a key `k`, it's best to write `h.hey?(k)` (or the alias `h.has_hey?(k)`), just in case `h` has a key `nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `key?` :)

Comment: Hey, @Sergio, these old eyes seem to have some trouble reading the tiny font on my phone in low light. Also, this demonstrates one of the pitfalls of cutting-and-pasting.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I had been aware of .to_a but that gives me the keys and values in vertical line for each.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yes, array. My attempt to get them in array has been futile so far. Even with .to_a the output is vertical presentation, not as an array.

Comment: @AlfatahKader: "that gives me the keys and values in vertical line" - no, it doesn't. Try my line exactly as is.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, DOPE! Me being a newbie, I didn't see the difference between "p" vs "puts" . Yep, it works. 

The work around otherwise that I figured is:

two_sum(array, x).each do |k, v|
puts "[#{k}, #{v}]"

Comment: @AlfatahKader I've done my best to correct your indentation and line breaks but you should make an effort to do this on your own in future questions. The harder your code is to read and decipher the less likely you are to get meaningful answers.

Comment: @anothermh, will do; I haven't figured out yet the conventional standard; just plunged into Ruby; will lookup some reading on this. thanks

Comment: @AlfatahKader: I'll just leave this here: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Just a word on formatting code. When it's within a sentence surround it with `backticks` (like so, with no spaces between the backtick and the code). In the body, indent 4 or more spaces. The easiest way to do that is to write your code with the only indenting the usual 2 spaces within `do...end` blocks, `if...elsif.,.end` and so on. Then select all your code and click on the symbol `{}`, That will indent all your code 4 spaces

Comment: @sawa - your edit lacks clarity and coherency in implicit English language usage for layman's understanding. Leaving out key word "Ruby" from the question is a fatal mistake that would render false positives for others asking similar question for a different program. If a certain key word or technical term is absent or incorrectly used, please comment.The end user's search experience is very important. You also edited out some tags. Please, again, I know you mean well, but let me correct myself and just comment the advice to me. I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: @AlfatahKader The fact that it is a Ruby question is supposed to be expressed by the keyword. No need to duplicate that in the title. "Ruby: " is so often seen, and is so often corrected. It is an incorrect way to "tag" a question. You need not, and should not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Credit: @SergioTulentsev

A correction was needed in final line to:

```
p two_sum(array, x).to_a
```

Instead of "puts", "p" and suffix .to_a solved the issue

Comment: It's best, imo, to put the credit in a comment, to keep the answer clean. For a simple line of code like this there's no need for the buttons to run or copy the code. It's just clutter, considering how simple it is for the reader to run or copy the code. Instead just add "prints" and then on the next line, indented 4 spaces `[[1, 4], [2, 3]]`,  Lastly, surround `puts`, `p` and `to_a` with backticks, rather than quotes (and terminate that sentence with a period). btw, don't forget there's an "edit" button on the question (to change "set" to "array", for example).